# Add more than 1000 picklist values in visualforce page (controller 1000 list items limit)

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I have following code -

Page -

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectContactId}" multiselect="false" size="1" id="RelatedContact">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!relatedContacts}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Controller -

```
public List<SelectOption> getRelatedContacts() 
{
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('', '-None-'));
    if(opportunityObj != null && GeneralUtil.CheckBlank(opportunityObj.accountid))
    {
        for(Contact contactObj: [select id,name from contact where accountid=:opportunityObj.accountid limit 999]) //controller can have only 1000 items in list :(
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption(contactObj.id, contactObj.name));
        }
    }
    return options;
}
```

this doesn't work for more than 1000 values any ways to get around this ?

Comment: Perhaps only show the picklist after the user has entered at least one filter character. 1000 entries will make your UI unusable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd say "you're doing it wrong" ;)

Every time you're hitting a limit like that you should stop and ask if that's really what you need to do. Even if you'd be able to input 50K contacts here - what would usability of such monster be? How is user expected to scroll through this? I'd say a lookup with a search function is really the way to go, that's what it is for.

Have you considered using an autocomplete? Jeff Douglas's blog contains a really [nice example on dynamic search](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/07/13/building-a-dynamic-search-page-in-visualforce/) - it's not exactly autocompletion but you shouldn't have too much trouble modifying it.

An alternative might be @BobBuzzard's [VF lookup](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/visualforce-lookup.html)

Or simply marry [jqueryUI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) and a [@RemoteAction](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_js_remoting.htm)

---

But if you insist on reading further... ;)

```
public class picklistTest{
    public String selectedVal {get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> getOptions1(){
        List<SelectOption> retVal = new List<SelectOption>();
        for(Integer i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
            retVal.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i+1), String.valueOf(i+1)));
        }
        return retVal;
    }
    public List<SelectOption> getOptions2(){
        List<SelectOption> retVal = new List<SelectOption>();
        for(Account a : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]){
            retVal.add(new SelectOption(a.Id, a.Name));
        }
        return retVal;
    }
    public List<SelectOption> getOptions3(){
        List<SelectOption> retVal = new List<SelectOption>();
        for(Contact c : [SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contact]){
            retVal.add(new SelectOption(c.Id, c.LastName));
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}

<apex:page controller="picklistTest">
<apex:form>
    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedVal}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!options1}"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Hi StackExchange" itemLabel="Hi StackExchange"/>
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!options2}"/>
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!options3}"/>
    </apex:selectList> 
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image: eh]

So you can get your query results, build a `<List<List<SelectOption>>` for example and then have a combo of `<apex:repeat>` + `<apex:selectOptions>`... I still advise against doing this though ;)

Comment: I understand in this use case it may be wrong .. but without typeahead, is there any way to get this. (instead of contacts , just consider I want to show picklist of cities more than 1000), is there any way to do it ?

Comment: I've just checked and it seems selectOption doesn't like having an embedded repeat. You'll really have to offload it to `options1`, `options2` etc I think (data could still sit in a list of lists, just a bunch of copy-paste getters to retrieve it. And I'd go autocomplete / lookup route anyway, based on size of data rather than it's nature ;) "London, United Kingdom" or "London, Ohio, United States"?

Answer (score 2):

The limit 1000 is applicable for any `List` that is shared across the `Page` and `Controller`(i.e. public lists). This is because of `viewstate` size. As everyone suggested, list is definitely not a proper solution to search or select from thousands of values. Just added up my point to mention this is applicable to any list and not only for `SelectOption`.

Comment: ... unless you use `<apex:page readOnly="true">` in which case limit goes up to 10K ;)

Comment: I din know that! +1!