# Collection size 1,002 exceeds maximum size of 1,000

Tags: visualforce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add more than 1000 picklist values in visualforce page (controller 1000 list items limit)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5018/add-more-than-1000-picklist-values-in-visualforce-page-controller-1000-list-ite)

i want to render apex:selectlist in visualforce page.with around 2000 options.
but it is giving me this error .what's the solution for this error.

Answer (score 2):

You can only list maximum 1000 elements in visual force pages components.
You can use a paginator to show 1000 elements max per page.

```
public static Integer ROWS_PER_PAGE = 1000;
public Integer pageNum {get; set;}
public Boolean pageHasMore {get; set;}
public List<SomeObject> list {get; set;}
public List<SomeObject> paginatedList {get; set;}
public Integer pageNum {get; set;}
public Boolean pageHasMore {get; set;}  
public Integer firstIndex {get; set;}

public contructor(){
     pageNum = 1;
     list = YOUR_LIST_WITH_DATA;
}

public void paginateList(){
    paginatedList = new List<SomeObject>();
    firstIndex = tableRowsPerPage * pageNum - ROWS_PER_PAGE ;
    pageHasMore = pageNum < getTotalPages();
    for(Integer i=firstIndex; i<firstIndex+ROWS_PER_PAGE && list.size() > i; i++){
       paginatedList.add(list .get(i));
}
}

public void nextPage(){
    pageNum++;
    paginateList();
}

public void previousPage(){
    pageNum--;
    paginateList();
}

public Integer getTotalPages(){
   if(System.Math.mod(list.size(), ROWS_PER_PAGE ) == 0)
      return list.size() / ROWS_PER_PAGE ;
   else
      return (list.size() / ROWS_PER_PAGE ) + 1;
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks Ivo Rocha.But i dont need pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice solution, check it out: [Work Around to Overcome Collection Size Limit of 1000 elements.](http://kuldeeptyagi.blogspot.de/2011/05/salesforce-work-around-to-overcome-1000.html)