# Collection size 9,301 exceeds maximum size of 1,000.

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have implemented this code but still it is giving me error

> Collection size 9,301 exceeds maximum size of 1,000.

I have Created List of List but it is giving me this error.

**Apex Class**

```
public with sharing class PaginationCon {

   public List<List<Attachment>> FinalList{get;set;}
   public List<Attachment> tempatt{get;set;}
    public List<Attachment> att{get;set;}

    public PaginationCon ()
    {
     att =new List<Attachment>();
     tempatt=new List<Attachment>();
     FinalList=new List<List<Attachment>>();


    for(Attachment a:[select id,Name,BodyLength,CreatedDate,Owner.Name from Attachment])
    {
        tempatt.add(a);

        if(tempatt.size()<0)
        {

            FinalList.add(tempatt);
        }    
    }
    FinalList.add(tempatt);

    }
}
```

**VisualForce Page**

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="PaginationCon">


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">

             $(function () {
            $("#example1").dataTable();            
        });          

    </script>

  <apex:form >
       <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>BodyLength</th>
                <th>Created Date</th>
                <th>Owner Name</th>
                <th>Click To View</th>
                <th>Click To Delete</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>
           <apex:repeat value="{!FinalList}" var="ftlist">
               <apex:repeat value="{!ftlist}" var="a">         
<tr>
    <td> <apex:outputText value="{!a.Name}"/></td>
    <td> <apex:outputText value="{!a.BodyLength}"/></td>
    <td> <apex:outputText value="{!a.CreatedDate}"/></td>
    <td> <apex:outputText value="{!a.Owner.Name}"/></td>
    <td> <apex:commandLink value="View"/></td>
    <td> <apex:commandLink value="Delete"/></td>
</tr>
    </apex:repeat>
  </apex:repeat>
 </tbody>

    </table>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This is a known limitation of `apex:repeat` tag. Please read this post, it has a very nice answer. [Add more than 1000 picklist values in visualforce page (controller 1000 list items limit)](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5018/add-more-than-1000-picklist-values-in-visualforce-page-controller-1000-list-ite) . Also there is a workaround however I would not recommend that. [Workaround](http://kuldeeptyagi.blogspot.de/2011/05/salesforce-work-around-to-overcome-1000.html). Have you considered using pagination as 9000+ plus items will increase your viewstate &make page loading slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use attribute readonly in apex:page

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="PaginationCon" readonly="true">
```